# Are there any way to directly return string value follwing method?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

I wrote a function to take store 'user' value. but I need to know, can I take string value directly and assign it to a variable ?

and my second question, if I cannot do it, how to take value from Observable.? currently I assign it to a local variable and using in the method. actually , that way is correct, I need to know how to remove return type.

```
readonly id$: Observable<string> = this.store.select(selectUser)
    .pipe(
     mergeMap((currentUser: CurrentUser) => {
        this.localid = currentUser.id; //assign local variable
        return currentUser.id; //retrn value
      }), shareReplayUntil(this.destroySub));
```

Comment: You don’t need a mergeMap here, just a map should suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can assign the value to a local/global variable inside the function.

If I understand well, `this.store.select` is an Observable. It depends on the type of Observable behind `this.store.select` but you can subscribe to an Observable to get the value. No needs of the `pipe` and `mergeMap`.

Sample example:

```
this.store.select(selectUser).subscribe(
  (currentUser: CurrentUser) => { // <-- here you will get the new value
    this.localid = currentUser.id; // <-- and you can assign it
  }
)
```

With your code :

```
this.store.select(selectUser)
.pipe(
 mergeMap((currentUser: CurrentUser) => {
    return currentUser.id; //return value to the subscribers
  }), shareReplayUntil(this.destroySub)
).subcribe(id => this.localid = id); // because of the mergeMap we get the id directly
```

An Observable is asynchronous, it doesn't return a value instantly. To get the value you have to subscribe to the Observable who will emit the new value to all the subscribers.

Comment: @acorbeli , are there any way to add 'shareReplayUntil(this.destroySub)' first code? (i will create seprate method and put your first code there...so , need to unsubcried it onDestroyMethod ?

Comment: You mean like this?
`this.store.select(selectUser)
  .pipe(shareReplayUntil(this.destroySub))
  .subscribe((currentUser: CurrentUser) => this.localid = currentUser.id
)`